# Closed Semi-Riemannian manifolds with non-compact isometry group

Tags: lie-groups, semi-riemannian-geometry, lorentzian-geometry, isometry-groups

Does anyone know a good reference for general results about closed Semi-Riemannian manifolds which have a non-compact isometry group?

Edit: My goal is to understand a bit better what the intuition behind compactness / non-compactness of the isometry of a closed Semi-Riemannian manifold is. For example are there topological restrictions on the underlying space? An example of the kind of statements I'm looking for is the following theorem (for Lorentzian manifolds):

**Theorem:** Let $(M,g)$ be a closed, simply connected Lorentz manifold and assume $M$ and $g$ are analytic. Then the isometry group of $M$ is compact.

Comment: There are quite a few results about pseudo-Riemannian manifolds. Could you please be more specific about what is it that you want to get?
In any case, here is a nice construction of a PR-manifold with a reach group of isometries. Let $G$ be a semisimple group and use left translations of the killing form on $T_eG$ to obtain a PR-structure on $G$. By the conjugation invariance of the form, this structure is also right invariant. Take a cocompact lattice $\Gamma<G$ and form the quotient structure on $G/\Gamma$. The left action of $G$ on this space will be by isometries.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I adjusted my question accordingly. To your construction: so whenever $G$ is non-compact this yields an example of a compact PS-manifold $G/\Gamma$ with non-compact isometry group (and if $G$ is compact itself, then the metric on $G$ would be Riemannian), right?

Comment: take a look here: http://www.ihes.fr/~/gromov/PDF/1[74].pdf

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look at it. I have a question to your construction: Can we say anything about the signature of the PR-metric we obtain from the Killing form? In the case of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ it has signature $(2,1)$. Do all signatures appear?

Comment: take a look here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.08695.pdf

Comment: No, not all signatures appear by the construction above. For example the lorentzian signature $(n,1)$ appears only for $n=2$. In fact the only non-compact simple group acting on a compact lorentzian manifold is $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ (up to local isomorphism).

Comment: I have a (possibly stupid) question about the paper. I wonder if there is a reason why the author uses quotients $\Gamma \backslash \widetilde{PSL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ instead of $\widetilde{SL}(2,\mathbb{R}) / \Gamma$?. The first thing I ask myself is, if both constructions yield isometric spaces (so does it matter if we take the left or right quotient)? And the second question is: is there any reason he writes $\widetilde{PSL}$ instead of $\widetilde{SL}$? As far as I know those to spaces are the same (since $SL$ covers $PSL$ two sheeted), but during the whole paper he writes $\widetilde{PSL}$.

Comment: regarding left and right: I believe it is absolutly symmetric and you have to break this symmetry by an arbitrary choice - as usual. Regarding PSL vs. SL: again it is just a matter of convention. Maybe it is more elegant to use PSL_2 as the base space because it is adjoint. I do not think it matters much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course there is D’Ambra's 1988 paper "Isometry groups of Lorentz manifolds", from which the theorem you state is taken.
A later paper, taking a more general perspective, is [this one](http://www.ihes.fr/~/gromov/PDF/1[74].pdf) by D’Ambra and Gromov from 1991.

Zimmer's school had its impact then, with Kowalski's thesis from 1994 and further papers by Zimmer, Adams, Stuck, Witte-Morris and Iozzi.

Later contribution was made by Zeghib's school and in particular Charles Frances.

There are many other contributions. Take a look at the list of participants of [this conference](http://cs.slu.edu/~scannell/lorentz/).
Many of the later contributions are in the language of Cartan geometries or rigid geometric structures etc. so you might miss them by a careless literature briefing.

My advice it to look at some of Frances' late papers, such as [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.08695.pdf), and the references there.
Maybe even better: make a contact with Frances who is actively working on the subject.

---

Let me add just a little bit of actual mathematics.

Let $G$ be a semisimple Lie group. Then its Killing form is an $\text{Ad}$-invariant non-degenerate symmetric form on its Lie algebra, which I identify here the tangent space at the identity.
It is definite iff $G$ is compact.
Applying left translations we obtain a pseudo-Riemannian structure on $G$ which is both left and right translation invariant. 
Picking a cocompact lattice $\Gamma<G$ we form a quotient manifold $G/\Gamma$ and endow it with the quotient pseudo-Riemannian structure (note that $G\to G/\Gamma$ is a covering map). The left action of G on this space will be by isometries.
The particular example of $G=\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ will give us a 3-dimensional compact Lorentzian manifold endowed with a non-trivial continuous action of $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ by isometries.
In a sense, this is as large as a group of isometries of compact Lorentzian manifold can get: non-compact simple Lie groups other then (locally) $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ have no non-trivial continuous action of on compact Lorentzian manifolds.
Similar theorems (with larger sets of exceptions) could be proved for pseudo-Riemannain manifolds with higher signatures.